# Excel Multiple Text to Column Convert Six Digit Dates (mm/dd/yy) to Eight (mm/dd/yyyy)

Tags: excel, vba, date

The code (recorded macro) I posted below uses text to column to change a date with six digits (mm/dd/yy) to eight (mm/dd/yyyy) in one column. The code stays in the same column.

```
Sub ConvertYears()
Range("Table_Wholesale8[Proceed_ECD]").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("J2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 3), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End Sub
```

My issue is that I need to do this to multiple columns at once. Solutions that could help is having that Macro loop through columns and convert columns that are in the date format or in columns (J:AT).

Please note that I am very new to VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Looping the code would look something like this: (the column number for J is 10 and AT is 46)

```
Sub ConvertYears()
    Dim i as integer
    For i = 10 to 46
        Range(chr(i+64) & "2").Select
        Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Cells(2, i), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(1, 3), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Next i 
End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting "Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of 'object_Global' failed

Comment: I fixed the line that was giving the error. Give it a try now to see if that fixed the issue. If not, let me know

Comment: t now highlights columns 5,6,7, and 8. The error message is: TexttoCoulmns method of Range class failed.

Comment: Try it again, see if changing it from Cell(...) to Range(...) in line 4 fixes it